# What is DIN 338 for drill bits?

Tags: standards, drilling, hss

I'm looking around for drill bits, and I keep reading "DIN 338" everywhere.

What is DIN 338? And what does it mean when a retailer or manufacturer writes "DIN 338" on the product specification of a drill bit?

Comment: Have you checked who writes or authors "DIN 338"?

Comment: Google search works: https://webstore.ansi.org/Standards/DIN/DIN3382006?gclid=CjwKCAiA4KaRBhBdEiwAZi1zzpjYel74laHrUrnw8RG5WAfmmao9GHPKKuNveFU9yYDj6CgYe-4yyBoCtxsQAvD_BwE

Comment: Sadly, it's not free, but often some careful sleuthing can locate a readable copy online.

Comment: Certainly nothing unusual in the title description,

Comment: @SolarMike: Well I understand that it is a DIN standard, so maybe written by DIN or some organization/committee associated with DIN. Why do you ask? I havent been able to figure out what the standard is about.

Comment: "Certainly nothing unusual in the title description", I dont understand what you mean. ?

Comment: @MadsSkjern Do you even understand that "DIN" is a consortium similar to ISO or ANSI?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft: Yes, I understood/understand what DIN is, and I understand that DIN 338 is a standard. But what does it say in this standard, and what does it mean when a manufacturer writes that their drill bits are "DIN 338"?